# How to change Ubuntu One Password?

Tags: ubuntu-one, login, password, login-screen

I'm using *Ubuntu 11.10* and having problem as under:

I have My User Account password and when I open ***"System Settings >> User Accounts"*** the dialog get unlocked by providing current password. Also when I open Terminal1 it asks for password; I give the same password above and it works.

The problem comes where I open Ubuntu One It asks Me password and only works if I give My Old Password of My User Account which I changed earlier. Also aother noticable thing is; User Account Dilog and Terminal needs password to process further but when I Log Out and need to log in again it shows Me list of User Accounts (Me, Guest Etc.) it not demands for password although it shows ***Login button*** on that place!

Please Help Me to Change The Password for Ubuntu One and to create a ONE ONLY password for all this!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you configured your Ubuntu One's password in order to be the same as in your User Account, that's why Ubuntu One seems to be "unlocking when you provide your ***old password***"

Ubuntu One's password can be changed directly on the website at https://one.ubuntu.com/account/ and after logging in, you can go to "My Account" at the top right corner,

[image]

which will send you to your Account Details, where you can "***Edit your account details in Ubuntu Single Sign On***"

[image]

If you set your Ubuntu One's password to be the same as your modified User Password then you can recover your "**ONLY ONE password for all this!**"

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You Very Much to giving time to answer My question, I'll try your suggested way and ll comment soon the solution! Thank You Very Much again!

Comment: I got your answer and I tried the same but it's just changing my password on website not Ubuntu One Software which is installed in my computer!

Comment: After changing your password in the website you MUST use the same password (and save it if needed) in your Ubuntu One's client. (The program that you use to get synced in the cloud) Give this a try and please inform if you succeded. Have a nice day.

Comment: Its Not working, I created new User Account for same problem and removed my device from Ubuntu One Website. Now I'm going to add as new device from new user account!